# Can I add a registration form to a Wordpress.COM page?

Tags: wordpress.com

I want to create a simple registration form site for free in the fastest way possible.

WordPress seems appropriate, but I am not sure, whether the (**free**) .COM version supports such registration forms. Does it?

If it does, where can I find it?

Comment: Downvoter care to explain?

Comment: @jonsca The Wordpress.COM site is an interface/application to create a site. The wordpress.ORG (website development) SE site sends users with Wordpress.COM problems here. You should consider this on the meta with the wordpress.org people. Also you have a Wordpress.COM tag and that already justifies this question.

Comment: I did miss the nuance there, so I apologize. I will reopen this for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further research I found what I was looking for.

There is no "Registration form" option in the **free** .COM flavor wordpress.

There is on the other hand a contact form. You can find it in the Add page editor in WP-admin as "add contact form".
You can customize this to your liking, add fields including radio and check buttons, simple text and such.

Then you can review the sent information in the WP-admin Feedback page, including downloading everything as CSV.